# How to mount a container's directory in a docker run command

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a "build container" which simply builds an output file from source code and then exits. So I have to bind mount the source code directory when running this build container so that it can build the output file.

The complicated part is that the source code directory is inside a separate container.

One solution is to manually copy the source code directory from the separate container to the docker host. Then I can give the path to the source code directory on the docker host, like `docker run --mount type=bind,src=/path/to/sourcecode,dst=/local build_container`.

The separate container has access to the docker socket so I can issue docker commands directly from it. I would like to be able to run the "build container" from this separate container so that the docker daemon magically knows that the source directory is on this separate container.

Is there a way to do that without having to manually copy the source code directory back to the docker host?

Comment: A docker container seems an odd way to distribute source code. Can't you provide your source an any other way, like git or any other version control system?

Comment: good question, so the reason my source code is in a container is because that is my IDE (this container has vim, tmux, language runtimes installed etc). it is convenient to write code in the container since all the tools are setup in it. the issue i'm running into with this is that using `docker run build_container` is not convenient because there is no easy way to tell docker daemon the correct path to my source code

Comment: You could mount the source code from your machine into the "dev container" and at the same time into the "build container". This would remove the necessity to do any docker magic.

Comment: good point. i think that may be the best solution if there are no other alternatives. although that would make me more dependent on the docker host. for example, when I run the "build container" I will have to ensure that I use the correct path to the source code on the docker host instead of the immediate `PWD` on the dev container